# Another useless try to ask a question

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I've ask a question. Described it as simple as it was possible.

After a while edited my question with some articles I've found. Edited it for the second time with more links.

I came up with my solutions on this subject, but there isn't any response to my question.

Here's the question:

[Best Practices - Stored Procedure Logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938093/best-practices-stored-procedure-logging/)

Is it still asked wrong or not interesting?

Comment: It's 8:45 on a Sunday morning on a holiday weekend here in the U.S. (east coast) as I write this, and that question is only 3 hours old.  Your question probably isn't getting a lot of attention because site traffic is low right now.

Comment: It's 5 p.m. here. Working day for me. Didn't thought of that:)))

Comment: For some reason, I have a bad habit of asking the questions I consider important between Friday midnight and Sunday afternoon. By the time traffic hits the site, my question has fallen off the front page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to give it more than three hours on a Sunday -- and particularly when you're asking a fairly broad "best practices" question.

You have the right idea of coming back to refine and improve your question, however!

Comment: Everything's fine. I got very good answers:)